# Follow new requests on google chrome devtools network tab

Tags: google-chrome, networking, devtools

On my website, an AJAX script makes a lot of requests. I would like to have the network log scroll down to the newest requests automatically without me needing to do this. How would I do this on Chrome DevTools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a somewhat cumbersome solution:

1. Open `devtools-on-devtools`.

> Open devtools first and switch its Dock side in the menu to a detached (floating) window
> [image]
> in the now detached devtools press Ctrl+Shift+i or ⌘+⌥+i on MacOS,
> which will open devtools-on-devtools in a new window

2. Run this code in `devtools-on-devtools` console:

```
setInterval(() => {
    let scr = document.querySelector("div.network-waterfall-v-scroll")
    scr.scrollTop = scr.scrollHeight
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried on chrome and it does it automatically.